# how to return value in textbox using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

when i select dropdown value it gives me price but removes all previous value.
how to return product name and dropdown value after it execute below ajax code?
function refresh_load is a ajax function.

```
enter code here
 <div class="product_sub"><input type="text" name="prod[]" id="prod0" size="30" class="input_box" onkeyup="autocomp()"/><input type="hidden" name="txt_pid[]" id="txt_pid0" /></div>
            <div class="product_sub"><select name="price" id="price" class="input_box" onchange="refresh_load()"><option value="">Select</option>
            <option id="billing_price" value="Billing Price">Billing Price</option>
            <option id="selling_price" value="Selling Price">Selling Price</option></select></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function refresh_load()     
{
 //alert('hi');
 var price=document.getElementById('price').value; 
 var prodid=document.getElementById('txt_pid0').value; 

 var xmlhttp;       
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {   
                //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                //document.images['imgtrue1'].src="../images/"+xmlhttp.responseText.split("#t#")[0];
                document.getElementById("rate").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
    }           
        //xmlhttp.open("GET","ref_cat_class.php?val="+val+"&val2="+val2,true);
        //alert(p);     
            xmlhttp.open("GET","refresh_page.php?price="+price+"&prodid="+prodid,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            //alert('hiii');

               document.getElementById("frmmonthly").reset();           
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function refresh load is having this line,

`document.getElementById("frmmonthly").reset();`

which is resetting your form values.

Comment: If I want to return textbox value after it execute ajax code how can i return it?

Comment: i did not understood your comment please add details of what do you mean by "want to return textbox value"

Comment: Its totally different from above question. Right now i am doing a task on other page where i did serch engine optimization. In that when i type a letter i matches word in database and shows the result like google. but after that when i filter it, it removes all the data in that text box which i want to pass on other page. So that data i want to return.

Comment: The javascript which i used is as below...




<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
 $("#users").autocomplete("get_course_list2.php", {
   width: 260,
   matchContains: true,
   mustMatch: true,
   //minChars: 0,
   //multiple: true,
   //highlight: false,
   //multipleSeparator: ",",
   selectFirst: false
  });
  $("#users").result(function(event, data, formatted) { 
  //alert(val(data[0]));
  $("#txt_sid").val(data[1]);
  //alert(val(data[1]));
  });
 });
 </script>